# Is there any significance to the format of Aziz's name?

Tags: symbolism, name-significance, elif-shafak, the-forty-rules-of-love

One of the main protagonists in the outer frame story of Elif Shafak's *The Forty Rules of Love* is a man named **Aziz Z. Zahara**. This name immediately struck me because of its interesting relationship with the alphabet: his first name (like the alphabet) starts with A and ends with Z, while his last name starts with Z and ends with A. Given that it's not his real name but one he chose for himself, and that [he discusses the significance of letters in his life](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8452/17), I wondered if there's some hidden meaning or symbolism behind this name.

**Is there any significance to the fact that his name goes "A...z Z Z...a"?**